# Find the limit of a recursive sequence with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, limits, recurrence-relations

Let the following recursive sequence:
$$a(0)=\alpha\in\mathbb R;\ a(n+1)=\max\{1/2,a(n)^2\}$$
find the limit as n goes to infinity.
[image]

Work: (wondering what's wrong on my answer. Thank you very much)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three cases,

$|\alpha| > 1$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a(n) = +\infty$

$|\alpha| = 1$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a(n) = 1$

$|\alpha| < 1$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a(n) = 1/2$

Comment: Where in particular I am failing?

Comment: I don't understand how you conclude the increasing and decreasing of the sequence. Many cases are considered in your attempt, I cannot track them

Comment: I obtain the increasing or decreasing studying the sign of a(n)-a(n+1), but considering only the case in which a(n)^2>1/2 (since for a(n)^2<1/2 the sequence has constant value d.v.)

Comment: Treating this sequence by its general term doesn't seem to be very useful to me, but even confusing. Everything is determined by $\alpha$ for this sequence, I hope my answer was useful to you!

Comment: So I should rewrite the sequence as $a(n+1)=max\{1/2,\alpha^{2^n}\}$?

Comment: You can do that if you want, it is not wrong

Comment: Could you consider accepting the answer, if it was helpful of course ? thanks in advance!